# root privilege is not working on chmod in android adb shell

Tags: command-line, android, adb

```
shell@android:/system/etc/wifi # 
shell@android:/system/etc/wifi # ls -l  
-rw-r--r-- root     root          326 2013-12-19 14:37 p2p_supplicant.conf
-rw-r--r-- root     root          282 2013-12-19 14:37 wpa_supplicant.conf
shell@android:/system/etc/wifi # echo 'hello' > file.txt                       
sh: can't create file.txt: Read-only file system
1|shell@android:/system/etc/wifi #
```

why is it not working..?

Comment: let me counter this with a question: why do you assume root can be allowed to create a new file or edit a file on a read-only filesystem? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your root privileges on your PC/Laptop/... are completely irrelevant for the file system on your smartphone.

Therefore

```
adb root;
adb shell mount -o rw,remount /;
```

Comment: It is showing an error  "adbd cannot run as root in production builds".